# How to implement google plus login into my Iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement google+ login in to my application, like facebook login.For fetching their contact details.I have gdata API.But i don't know what are the procedures to implement that in to my class.Is there any sample application ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit broad - what have you tried already? The easiest way to use [google+ login API call](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) should be inside a [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Write up an html page using the API sample code then load it up inside your app. Check google for a good [tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/API/google-plus/tutorial.php).